# Running programs close when the screen goes to sleep

Tags: ubuntu

Whenever the screen turns off after a while or when you close the lid on the notebook, all programs are closed, as if the section had been closed. This started to occur after I formatted and reinstalled Ubuntu.

Comment: Does https://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid helps ?